# How to read from an Azure Page Blob with concurrent writes?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm calling the `downloadRange`-function from the Azure Storage SDK for Java (v4.0.0) to download parts of a Page Blob, e.g. `downloadRange(0, 1000, os, null, null, null)`. Another process, a single writer, writes to the end of the page blob. If a write is concurrent to the `downloadRange`-call AND `downloadRange` does a retry internally (HTTP GET ) it results in a `StorageException` with the following text: "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.".

Is it possible to perform the `downloadRange` read operation without this happening? In terms of the application, it is safe to access the bytes up until the last page.

The pseudo-code is as follows (using scala):

```
val blob = container.getPageBlobReference(blobName)
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
blob.downloadRange(0, totalSize, baos, null, null, null)
```

**Update**

Clarification based on the comments below. The use case is a bit special since the read byte range is known to be safe, i.e. it only reads the range of bytes in the blob which are not written to concurrently. The write is only appending to the end of the blob. The question is how to use `downloadRange` or any other part of the Azure Storage SDK to access the blob with concurrent writes, even in the case of network issues (packet loss, slow transfer, etc.).

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see a Conditional header error either unless you ended up doing retries. I can't repro the issue though -- when I send it and investigate in Fiddler there's no conditional headers and no resulting error. If you could post 1. A trace (from a tool like Fiddler) of the download request with any sensitive info removed and 2. what version of the lib you're using, that would help.

Comment: Also note: You can just use downloadRange(0, totalSize, baos) without the nulls.

Comment: I used wireshark to look at the complete trace. Initially there is a GET to retrieve the blob. After ~41s the server-side closes the TCP connection (RST ACK). When the client retries with a new GET it includes an If-Match header with an ETag part of the response of the initial GET. This triggers the error since a write has occurred during the download. Is it possible to avoid sending the If-Match header on the retry?

Comment: Yeah, the retry is the issue here. (Can you update your question with that detail?). The if-match gets set because on retry we have to guarantee that the blob has not changed in order to have consistency. Otherwise if a new blob had been set between these calls we'd get half of the old and half of the new, for example. The root problem seems to be the TCP reset. How big is the blob and is the network particularly slow?

Comment: The blob is ~32MB and the download is slow from that particular storage account (0.5-1MBps). From other storage accounts in the same DC I get 3-4MBps on the same connection. Regarding the root problem, IMHO the issue is with the semantics of `downloadRange`. In terms of consistency, the first GET is a "best-effort" read, i.e. a writer can change any page in the blob (before or after the current read offset). The second GET is an optimistic read that only succeeds if there hasnt been any change since the first GET. Thus, its the same as calling `downloadRange` with an If-Match AccessCondition.

Comment: Can you explain again the last comment? I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean by the root problem. Retries have to be guarded for the reason I explained above or your data becomes inconsistent. The first read is not best effort in any sense -- since storage is atomic it will get what came before it and nothing that came after. The second read as a retry has to honor that.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear and thanks for clarifying that downloadRange is atomic with respect to the entire page blob. For my use case I can guarantee that the data returned by read is consistent as long as the range is up to a certain offset. Any concurrent write will always be after the offset. So its perfectly fine for the application to read a range using `downloadRange`, unless the connection breaks down and there is a retry with the If-Match header.

Comment: Okay, understood. From a library perspective since we don't have that knowledge we have to enforce. There's not a way to disable that. This combo of connection failures, concurrent writes AND foreknowledge of read safety is honestly just not something we have encountered and I'd expect to be generally very rare. The connection failures being the rarest part which is why I suggest more investigation there. If you really think that is expected for one reason or another with your application I'd maybe recommend breaking down your reads into smaller chunks to hopefully reduce the likelihood.

Comment: If the last comment makes sense to you, could you please update your question and I can write a full answer rather than a comment for posterity's sake?

Comment: I've added an update, but feel free to improve the question if its still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on the comment thread you can read above.

In this particular case, the error is occurring on a retry and not the first call. When the storage library retries a download the if-match gets set because on retry we have to guarantee that the blob has not changed in order to have consistency. Otherwise if a new blob had been set between these calls we'd get half of the old and half of the new, for example. From a library perspective since we don't have the knowledge the subsequent reads will be safe if the blob has changed we have to enforce this. There's not a way to disable that.

In this particular case there is a very unique combination of frequent connection failures, concurrent writes AND foreknowledge of read safety. This is something I'd expect to be generally very rare. The connection failures would be the rarest part so that probably needs more investigation (perhaps a topic for another question).

In this special case I'd recommend doing whatever you can to reduce the amount of time the network is open. Reducing this time means hitting less network failures in the first place reduces the likelihood that the blob has changed if a retry does happen since a small download will simply take less time. Breaking down your reads into smaller chunks is probably the best route to accomplish this. Similarly, you may want to simply manually retry this small portion of the download in the catch statement for this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue `StorageException` seems to be caused by not setting up the argument `AccessCondition` for the function `downloadRange` of Class `CloudBlob`.

About Azure Storage concurrency, I recommend the offical document [Managing Concurrency in Microsoft Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-concurrency/). There are some code samples in C# as references. You can try to refer to [the Javadocs of Azure Storage SDK](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/) and translate these code in Java.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I have tried to add the ifNoneMatch("*") to the request, but the exception is still thrown. Looking at the REST API documentation for GET Blob, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx, I assume that it could be successful without conditional HTTP headers.

Comment: @mkhq Please see the section `Supported Conditional Headers` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179371.aspx, it said *"Specify the wildcard character (\*) to perform the operation only if the resource does not exist, and fail the operation if it does exist."* Can you share your code for troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: I've updated the question with some basic code. I'm not using any conditional headers and expect that `downloadRange` is not adding anything when the AccessCondition is `null`.